# How to designate a foreign key in a dependency diagram

Tags: database, normalization

I just need to know how a foreign key is defined.

When I create the diagram I know that the primary key is supposed to be underlined, but how is the foreign key defined?  Is it also underlined?

Answer (score 0):

For a dependency diagram you use a dashed underline.

Comment: i was talking about a dependency diagram for 3NF

Comment: @john: Edited for dependency diagram